# How to see all git commands in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

Is is possible to see the commands PhpStorm executes when i e.g. do a "push" and than rebase it?

Sometimes i do not know what PhpStorm is doing when i do a "push" and than "merge" or "rebase", it stahes sometimes thing and so on...

Would be great to see all commands PhpStorm executes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the "Version Control" view (menu -> View -> Tool Windows -> Version Control) there is a tab called "Console".

The commands that change the status of the repository are displayed there together with their output, the current time (with milliseconds) and the directory where they run.

The tab is created only when it is needed. If you do only read-only operations on the repository (show log, compare files, check status) it is not present but it will appear as soon as you checkout a branch or commit something.

Answer (score 0):

Since PhpStorm 2020.1:

The tool window `Version Control` was renamed to the name of the VCS your project uses, e.g. `Git`, `Subversion`, `Mercurial` or `Perforce`:

[image: View Tool Window Git]

[image: Tool Window Git]